# Insert string in other string at index even if it's out of it

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to insert "OK" at index (i.e. 20) in a string even if the index is out of the string.

For example :

```
|       INPUT        |           OUTPUT             |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|   "hello world"    |   "hello world         OK"   |
|       "foo"        |   "foo                 OK"   |
| "any large string" |   "any large string    OK"   |
```

I've tried with String.Format... :

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("hello world{0,20}", "OK"))
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("foo{0,20}", "OK"))
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("any large string{0,20}", "OK"))
```

...but it doesn't correspond to the result I'd like to have.

Any idea on how can I do it ?

Comment: they still wont "line up" in a listbox if that is what you are after

Comment: You would have to measure the string you have and add the spaces that you need to get to 20.

Comment: What if string is 21 characters long? Is that possible?

Comment: @LarsTech I thought about this, but is there an easier way to do it with a built-in function like String.Format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pad the first string, not the `"OK"`:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", "hello world", "OK"))
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", "foo", "OK"))
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", "any large string", "OK"))
```

Note: This will add the `"OK"` after the first string, even if the first string is longer than 20 characters.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 1):

This works, I think:

```
Friend Shared Function InsertString(toInsert As String, 
                                    intoString As String, 
                                    atIndex As Integer, 
                                    Optional padChar As Char = " "c) As String

    Return If(atIndex > intoString.Length - 1, 
        intoString & New String(padChar, atIndex - intoString.Length) & toInsert,
        intoString.Insert(atIndex, toInsert))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I prefer use `String.Format` ;)